# How to create hover button in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

Id like to create similar animation effect with press button in flutter like [`this`](https://codepen.io/vitor-siqueira/pen/xNBExN)

I tried to find some similar widget on https://pub.dev/ without success. Any Idea how to create it?

Answer (score 0):

Use materialappbutton to get hover animation effect.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is working with a gradient which you adapt in a stateful way on hover.

See the below answer for how to make a gradient border:
[Outlined transparent button with gradient border in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55395641/outlined-transparent-button-with-gradient-border-in-flutter)