# How to create a gradient border for a container

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to replicate the following behavior:

[image]

Specifically the gradient on the border. I can easily copy this behavior by using two `Containers` stacked on each other: one that holds the radial-gradient (for the border) and another on top which is the background color. **However, that doesn't work for me as I want the background color to be partially transparent** so the content below this card is somewhat visible.

How else would you approach this? Use some sort of custom paint? Last case scenario I can just import the png and use it as a background but wanted to make this in code.

PS: You can create the following gradient by using a `RadialGradient` where the center is the same as the rectangle's center.

Comment: Check this answer may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/55638138/12413404

Comment: Ahh, thanks for posting this @esentis. I managed to reach a good solution which I'll post in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to do this by simply using a `CustomPainter` to create the border. Turns out it's pretty straightforward. Thanks to @esentis for helping out!

```
final gradient = RadialGradient(
  colors: [
    ThemeColors.BLUE,
    Colors.white.withAlphaPercent(0),
  ],
  radius: 1,
  center: Alignment.center,
);

final start = Offset(size.width * 0, size.height * 0);
final end = Offset(size.width * 1, size.height * 1);
final center = Offset(size.width * 0.5, size.height * 0.5);

final rect = Rect.fromPoints(start, end);
final rRect = RRect.fromRectAndRadius(rect, Radius.circular(12));
final paint = Paint()
  ..strokeWidth = 6
  ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
  ..shader = gradient.createShader(Rect.fromCircle(
    center: center,
    radius: size.width * 0.5,
  ));

canvas.drawRRect(rRect, paint);
```